# Swift - Could not cast value of type 'UINavigationController' to 'MapViewController'

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2

I'm currently trying to convert my Swift iOS app to Swift 2. I've managed to remove the compiler errors (with some great help from stackoverflow) but I'm running into issues with the app once it's compiled now. My app has a tabBarController with 3 tabs. When I select the 2nd tab, the app now crashes with a 'SIGABRT' error.

I get the error:

> Could not cast value of type 'UINavigationController' (0x106fbd588) to 'FlightTracker.MapViewController' (0x105722430)

For the following code:

```
let mapviewcontroller = self.tabBarController?.viewControllers?[0] as! MapViewController
```

Why can it not cast the controller as a MapViewController? I had it working this way prior to iOS 9 & Swift 2.

Comment: Because, as the message says, the first view controller in your tab bar controller's view controller array is a navigation controller, not a map view controller.  Since you mention the second tab, perhaps you want `viewControllers?[1]` not `[0]`?

Comment: That still gives me: `Could not cast value of type 'UINavigationController' (0x10661d588) to 'FlightTracker.MapViewController' (0x104d82430)`. I had my app working perfectly prior to the update with the `[0]` index. I'd be surprised if that had changed on it's own.

Comment: Ok, well that was just a guess as I can't see how your code and app is structured.  What I can tell you is that your tab bar's viewController array contains UINavigationControllers not a MapViewController.

Comment: Right, I understand. But how on earth do I peak inside of this array to verify things? Can I do this after the app has crashed the simulator?

Comment: You can use the debugger. You can set breakpoints and examine properties and so on, but it should be pretty straight-forward to analyse your view hierarchy - How are you setting everything up?  With storyboards or in code?

Comment: 99% of the UI was built with Storyboards.

Comment: Perhaps you had as? rather than as! previously and the conditional downcast was just failing silently

Answer (score 3):

It should work

```
let navigationController = self.tabBarController?.viewControllers?[0] as! UINavigationController //Check which is your tab on your storyboard, 0, 1, n ?

let mapviewcontroller = navigationController.viewControllers[0] as! MapViewController
```

self.tabBarController?.viewControllers?[0] => it's your UINavigationController

On your storyboard your tabBarController is connected to ***N*** UINavigationController**S** and one of your UINavigationController to your MapViewController.

Comment: When I change the index, I still get: `Could not cast value of type 'UINavigationController' (0x111c2d588) to 'FlightTracker.MapViewController' (0x110392430)`. As I mentioned, this exact index has worked fine prior to the update so I would be surprised if that changed?